# install python3 and pip3 without sudo right

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I tried to install python3 on a linux server without the admin right. I searched around as found something like

```
tar zxfv Python-3.11.tgz
find ~/python -type d | xargs chmod 0755
cd Python-3.11
./configure --prefix=$HOME/python --with-ssl=/usr/lib/ssl
make && make install
```

The installation was successful. But when I run the pip3 to install packages, it returns the error of SSL

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

The orignial python on the server can connect to pypi.org. I thought it may be some path error when the python3.11 was instlled without sudo right.

Any sugggestions? Thanks!

tried configured the ssl path as mentioned above, but not working.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/python --with-ssl=/usr/lib/ssl
```

Comment: `make` can succeed even without a correctly built SSL module, so it looks like your build did not correctly find the necessary openssl files.  What do you see for `python3.11 -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION_INFO)'` ?

Comment: When I tried to import ssl, it raised the error '_ssl' not found. I probably didn't build with the ssl module, but how should I do it? I used the 'openssl version -d' to find ssl path. When I pass the augment ' ./configure --prefix=$HOME/python --with-ssl=/usr/lib/ssl', there were two warnings: 'configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-ssl' and ''WARNING: pkg-config is missing.". any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Yes then it's as I suspected, the configure script is not correctly run. Added an answer explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build is missing the ssl module, because of an incorrect configure option provided:

```
--with-ssl
```

The correct configure option is:

```
--with-openssl
```

The path should be to the dir containing `include/openssl/ssl.h`, i.e. if you have

```
/path/to/openssl-1.1.1g/include/openssl/ssl.h
```

Then provide:

```
--with-openssl=/path/to/openssl-1.1.1g/
```

You'll see in the output of `./configure` whether `ssl.h` is found or not. Don't bother to run `make` until the `./configure` is correctly finding OpenSSL headers, otherwise you'll just end up with a broken build and no `_ssl` extension module available.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a virtual environment.

```
python3 -m venv 'whatever you want to name your virtual environment'
```

then you can pip install and your packages should be installed locally within the virtual environment

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I usually install packages with pip3 --user option. I thought the problem is more related ssl that can not connect to the server, other than the virtual env.

Comment: How would creating a venv fix the problem of the stdlib SSL module being unavailable? This answer is completely unrelated to the actual error.